# Does monaco editor support nested token?

Tags: javascript, r, regex, monaco-editor

I customized a language in monaco editor, there are two root tokens:

```js
[/^\[?[e|E][r|R][r|R][o|O][r|R]\]?\s.*/, 'error'],
[/\d{1,4}(-|\/|\.|:)\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4}/, 'time'],
```

With this definition, below line text will be rendered as a single error line:

`eRrOr This is an error line no 13:22:01 (special decorator)`

What I want is `13:22:01` rendered as time token and the rest rendered as error token. Is there any method that I can use make this OK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try something like this - trick is parentheses and the same amount of tokens in an array after (instead of a single string):

`[/(..error-regx..)(..time-regx...)/, ['error', 'time']]`